# Duplicate Log Messages in Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure App Service as a backend that is written using Node currently with verbose logging enabled. Within the application logs, I seem to always get duplicate log messages for various requests.

```
2018-02-28T16:26:33  PID[22384] Verbose     Received request: GET https://appname.azurewebsites.net/tables/TableOne?$filter=(email%20eq%20'stevejohns%40gmail.com')
2018-02-28T16:26:33  PID[22384] Verbose     Received request: GET https://appname.azurewebsites.net/tables/TableOne?$filter=(email%20eq%20'stevejohns%40gmail.com')
```

I have confirmed this issue isn't in my mobile application as the result is the same if I send a request from Postman. This leads me to believe I somehow have a second instance of something running in the service. I've looked through Kudu as much as possible but haven't come across any indication that would cause this logging issue.

Please see below for my current app.js and TableOne.js files.

Any tips are much appreciated!

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'), azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');
var app = express();

var mobile = azureMobileApps({
    homePage: true
});

mobile.tables.import('./tables');
mobile.api.import('./api');

mobile.tables.initialize()
.then(function () {
    app.use(mobile);    
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
});
```

**TableOne.js**

```
var azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');

var table = azureMobileApps.table();

table.access = 'authenticated';

table.name = 'TableOne';
table.maxTop = 1000;
table.softDelete = false;
table.dynamicSchema = false;
table.columns = {
    firstname: 'string',
    lastname: 'string',
    email: 'string',
    profilepictureurl: 'string',
    phonenumber: 'string'
};

table.insert(function (context) {
    return context.execute();
});

table.read(function (context) {
    return context.execute();
});

table.update(function (context) {
    return context.execute();
});

table.delete(function (context) {
    return context.execute();
});

module.exports = table;
```

Comment: How and where did you log these messages? Can you please share the code?

Comment: These logs are what the Azure App Service itself generates. I did enable them under the "Diagnostics Logs --> Application Logging (Filesystem) --> Level (Verbose)". I will add my Node.js code of the application itself and the table controller above. Both are basically stock.